# Node.js - Jsonwebtoken Calculate "iat" and "exp"

Tags: node.js, jwt

I'm setting up an API in Node.js and Express and I use JWT for authentication, which works really nice. The one thing I have not been able to figure out is how determine the exact date and time which associated with the IAT value. I know it's based on milliseconds, but I cannot relate this back to a date. The official JWT specification says:(https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#page-10)

> 4.1.6.  "iat" (Issued At) Claim
> The "iat" (issued at) claim identifies the time at which the JWT was
> issued.  This claim can be used to determine the age of the JWT.  Its
> value MUST be a number containing a NumericDate value.  Use of this
> claim is OPTIONAL.

For example:

```
"iat": 1479203274,
"exp": 1479205074,
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can build a date from a unix timestamp in **milliseconds** by doing

`var date = new Date( timestamp )`

So in your case, try doing :

`var date = new Date( parseInt("1479203274") * 1000 )`

The `*1000` is to convert seconds to milliseconds.
The `parseInt` is not necessary since javascript cast automatically the express to an `number`. It's just to make it cleared in intent.

Comment: Thanks! This really helps

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to specify the current timestamp if you follow the below. The current timestamp and expire timestamp will be taken automatically.

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
...

const payload = {
        "iss": "<your iss>",
        "sub": "<your sub>",
        "aud": "<your aud>"
    };
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(`my_sig_key.pem`);

const signed = jwt.sign(payload, privateKey, {
    algorithm: '<Your Algorithm>'
    expiresIn: '5s' //Its expires in 5seconds. You can set minute, hour too.
});

console.log("signed", signed);
```

And the final payload in the JWT will be

```
{
  "iss": "<your iss>",
  "sub": "<your sub>",
  "aud": "<your aud>",
  "iat": 1645869827,
  "exp": 1645869947
}
```